# WiX toolset build fails after upgrading from .net 4.0 to 4.6.1: Cannot load MSBuild wrapper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, wix

So after upgrading my whole project to 4.6.1 I'm getting this error thrown by heat when I build it:

```
Failed to load MSBuild wrapper object: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I also get

```
The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\Bin\heat.exe" project "C:\Project\Project.csproj" -projectname "Project" -pog Binaries -gg -sfrag -nologo -out "obj\\Release\Harvested XML\_Project.xml"" exited with code 5316. 86
```

The problem here is that the assembly binding log viewer is showing nothing, so I don't know where WiX is searching for the MSBuild version 12, or if it in fact exists and there's another underlying issue.

I checked a lot of SO answers and googled a lot too, but I couldn't find anything problem like this one. Of course I tried them but nothing worked.

Any ideas about this or why fuslogvw is showing nothing? That would help me a lot

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: fuslogvw output:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (28/04/2016 @ 12:28:06 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\Bin\heat.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/WiX Toolset v3.10/Bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = heat.exe
Calling assembly : WixVSExtension.MSBuild12, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ce35f76fcda82bad.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\Bin\heat.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/WiX Toolset v3.10/Bin/Microsoft.Build.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/WiX Toolset v3.10/Bin/Microsoft.Build/Microsoft.Build.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/WiX Toolset v3.10/Bin/Microsoft.Build.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/WiX Toolset v3.10/Bin/Microsoft.Build/Microsoft.Build.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: WIX....(shudder).   I would try re-installing WIX...maybe it will reinstall the missing dependecies.

Comment: How come I haven't tried that yet! I'll try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why fuslogvw is showing nothing, is it configured to log bind failures?

WiX is using the standard way to load assemblies (https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/VSExtension/wixext/VSProjectHarvester.cs#L1119)

```
msbuildWrapperAssembly = Assembly.Load(String.Format(MSBuildWrapperAssemblyName, shortVersion, thisAssemblyName.Version, publicKeyToken));
```

The wrapper has a direct reference to Microsoft.Build (https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/VSExtension/wixext/WixVSExtension.MSBuild12/WixVSExtension.MSBuild12.csproj#L23).

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

See [issue 4853](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4853) for an explanation of how heat decides which version of MSBuild to load.

Comment: Before you answered I got it to work by using the custom feature for some reason. I'll update my post with the info, but now I have something to work with! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Where's that Microsoft.Build supposed to be anyways? I can see the reference, but is that like the regular Microsoft.Build.dll?

Comment: @Damieh In the GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build)

Comment: Hi @Gaspa79, as you write it in a previous comment, can you please post the info about your "working configuration" or the workaround used please. I am facing the same problem,as Heat don't succeed in compiling my Framework 4.7 based project, and the FusLogvw.exe show that the Microsoft.Build.Dll is missing (and of course i don't find it in on my computer). Regards from Toulouse\France

Comment: @sstassin I'm so sorry, I forgot about this already and I don't have access to that code anymore =(

Comment: Maybe I've overread something... What exactly needs to be done in order to fix that problem? I've got the same error message after upgrading a solution to .NET 4.8 and trying to add WiX setup.

Answer (score 3):

This error can occur because HEAT is looking at the ToolsVersion of your .csproj file and using that to determine which version of the MSBuild.Tools assembly to load.  Changing this from '12.0' (or what have you) to the version of MSBuild that you use fixes this issue.

Comment: I have MSBuild 16, as part of VS 2019. I changed ToolsVersion to 16.0, but still facing the same issue. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

For older projects it can happen if [a specific version of MSBuild tools is needed](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5283#issuecomment-252661555).

> Close Visual Studio, and
> Install [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40760) (which is v12.0), or
> Install Microsoft Build Tools version shown in the `Microsoft.Build` error

**My specific scenario**

- Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (same in my VS 2022 Enterprise)
- Build error `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0...`
- Had also downgraded to WIX Toolset 3.11.1 (Dec-2017) from 3.11.2 (Sep-2019), not sure if that was necessary